# Copy-elision doesn't happen when using move

Tags: c++

Why does this example print:

```c++
#include <iostream>

struct X
{
    X() = default;
    X(X const&) { std::cout << "copy-constructor\n"; }
    X(X&&) { std::cout << "move-constructor\n"; }

    X& operator=(X)
    {
        return *this;
    }
};

int main() 
{
    X x, y;
    std::cout << "assign from prvalue calls the ";
    x = X{};
    std::cout << "\nassign from xvalue calls the ";
    x = std::move(y);
}
```

> assign from prvalue calls the
>   assign from xvalue calls the move-constructor

Both `X{}` and `std::move(y)` are rvalues so why does only assigning to `X{}` cause copy-elision?

Comment: implement `X& operator=(const X&)` and `X& operator=(X&&)`, and you will see

Comment: @BЈовић But they will be ambiguous with my assignment operator.

Comment: Yes, remove your assignment operator

Comment: Are you asking why the move constructor is not elided?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Copy elision works in the first case because you're initialising the assignment operator's parameter from a temporary; the temporary can be omitted, constructing the parameter directly instead. In the words of the standard, one of the criteria for elision is:

> when a temporary class object that has not been bound to a reference would be copied/moved to a class object with the same cv-unqualified type, the copy/move operation can be omitted by constructing the temporary object directly into the target of the omitted copy/move

In the second case, you're not initialising it from a temporary, but from an existing object. It has already been constructed, in a different location to the target, so the optimisation described above can't be done.